# Deprecated methods in Android Studio (AS) 1.1.0 (and Eclipse Luna) "Settings Activity"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

My app could have a couple of checkboxes that I'd rather the user didn't have to re-check each time the app is chased from memory. So I've been reading about preferences.

I'm not sure I've seen anything as complicated as "a modern fragment-based PreferenceActivity", so I was looking for guidance/example from AS 1.1.0, but I got code with a total of 9 references in 4 hunks of code to `addPreferencesFromResource`, `getPreferenceScreen`, and `findPreference`, all of which carry this blurb:

`This method was deprecated in API level 11. This function is not relevant for a modern fragment-based PreferenceActivity.`

To have the code presented with deprecated code by two IDEs is one thing; that there's no indication of what each method has been replaced by is another (but there's nothing replacing it, as it happens).

Would it really be that hard for AS to produce "a modern fragment-based PreferenceActivity"? If so, I guess I'm right about the complexity.

Am I missing something? Am I supposed to just write/extend deprecated code? Turn off compiler checking of deprecated stuff?

Does anyone know of a nice tutorial for (or an example of) a simple (like two checkboxes) "modern fragment-based PreferenceActivity"? Or ANYthing that saves preferences but isn't deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked, "Does anyone know of a nice tutorial for (or an example of) a simple (like two checkboxes) `modern fragment-based PreferenceActivity`? Or ANYthing that saves preferences but isn't deprecated?"

I do as of 9pm last night. *** EDITED 5/16/15 ***

Here is a complete, working preferences activity, though it doesn't have all drawable, mipmap, dimens, and values folders and files. I downloaded it from advice in Sams ***Teach Yourself*** Android App Development in 24 Hours and modified it. Emphasis mine.

[image]

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.whatever.prefs"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.whatever.prefs.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.whatever.prefs.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.whatever.prefs;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  public static final String SETTINGS = "com.whatever.prefs.settings";
  public static final String FIRST_USE = "com.whatever.prefs.firstUse";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    /* BAD IDEA--CREATES NEW SET OF PREFS 
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Do this v v v v v v v v v v v instead! */
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    boolean firstUse = preferences.getBoolean(FIRST_USE, true);
    if (firstUse){
      Toast helloMessage = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello First Time 
                                    User",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      helloMessage.show();
      Editor editor = preferences.edit();
      editor.putBoolean(FIRST_USE, false);
      editor.commit();
    }
    else {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Second+ use", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;

      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
}
```

SettingsFragment.java:

```
package com.whatever.prefs;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment 
                                    implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().
                                    registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
  @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().
                                  unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {    
       SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
                                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
       if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("pie_type")){
           Log.w("Settings", sharedPref.getString(key, ""));
       }
    }
}
```

res\menu\activity_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
</menu>
```

res\layout\activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Hi world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

res\layout\activity_settings.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">    
    <fragment android:name="com.whatever.prefs.SettingsFragment"
              android:id="@+id/settings_fragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Hour11App</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_settings">Settings</string>
    <string-array name="pie_array">
        <item>apple</item>
        <item>blueberry</item>
        <item>cherry</item>
        <item>coconut cream</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices. -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Holo.ButtonBar">
    <!-- Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
             res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
             backward-compatibility can go here.-->
    </style>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

SettingsActivity.java:

```
package com.whatever.prefs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String SETTINGS = "com.whatever.prefs.settings";
    public static final String FIRST_USE = "com.whatever.prefs.firstUse";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    }
}
```

dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

res\xml\preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="Images">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="hires"
            android:title="Hi-Res Images"
            android:summary="Show high quality images. These take longer to load"
            android:defaultValue="False" />
     </PreferenceCategory>
     <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="Pie Info">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="pie"
            android:title="Pie"
            android:summary="Like Pie"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
        <ListPreference
            android:dependency="pie"
            android:key="pie_type"
            android:title="Pie Type"
            android:summary="Preferred pie type for eating"
            android:dialogTitle="Type of Pie"
            android:entries="@array/pie_array"
            android:entryValues="@array/pie_array"
            android:defaultValue="apple" />
       <EditTextPreference
            android:key="more_info"
            android:title="More Info"
            android:summary="More about pies"
            android:defaultValue="" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceScreen
            android:key="second_preferencescreen"
            android:title="Second Screen of Settings">
         <EditTextPreference
            android:key="extraA"
            android:title="More Data"
            android:summary="Another EditTextPreference"
            android:defaultValue="" />
         <EditTextPreference
            android:key="ExtraB"
            android:title="Even More Info"
            android:summary="What more can we say"
            android:defaultValue="" />
     </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```